Making a CFG for $L = {a^i b^j c^k d^m : i + 2j = 3k + m; i, j, k, m>= 0}$?
I am trying to construct a context-free grammar (CFG) for the following language:
$L = \{a^i  b^j  c^k  d^m : i + 2j = 3k + m; \, i, j, k, m \geq 0\}$
So far, I've tried doing something like this:
$S = aaaaSQ$
$S = aabAQ$
$S = bbAQ$
$S = bbAQ$
$A= bbAQ$
where Q iw the possible arrangements of c and d for 1 multiple of 4 (cd, dddd, and QQ could make ccdd, dddddddd, cddddd)
$Q = cQd$
$Q = ddddR$
$R = ddddR$
...
but I don't think this is working because of the Q part which seems really logically wrong.

Most likely, yes, this question was presented on the topic of context-free grammars, however I would be interested to know if there could be a non context-free grammar solution to this.

In this case it might be easier to construct a pushdown automaton first.
Notice, that
$$i + 2j = 3k + m \iff (i + 2j) - 3k - m = 0$$
so use the stack to count the value of $(i + 2j) - 3k - m$ by pushing/popping the right amount of counters for each symbol and check that you input has the form $a^*b^*c^*d^*$.
Then you can translate your automaton to a CFG.

How do we check whether a string in $a^*b^*c^*d^*$ belongs to $L$?
We read the string from left to right. In the first part we read $a$'s and $b$'s and build a credit by adding $+1$ and $+2$ for these letters. Then in the second phase we read $c$'s and $d$'s and spend that credit, $-3$ and $-1$ respectively. In the end we should be even, and end in $0$.
This is how a pushdown automaton would work, pushing and popping these values on/from the stack.
A context-free grammar cannot store these values, at least not unbounded values. However it can work from both sides of the string. Store a limited credit in the nonterminal, we can earn credit (generating the letter to the left) and spend it (generating a letter to the right).
For example $S_2 \to a S_3$, and  $S_3 \to S_0 c$.
In this partial solution the $a$'s and $b$'s are not yet in the proper order. The nonterminals should take care of that, similarly how the states of a finite state automaton can force that order.
The resulting grammar will be linear, a subclass of the context-free grammars.
